# Using untyped datasets in Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm creating a runtime dataset in page load. In this dataset I'm adding columns like that:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument orpt = 
   new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();

DataTable table = new DataTable("DataSet1");

table.Columns.Add("Fname", typeof(System.String));
table.Columns.Add("Lname", typeof(System.String));
table.Columns.Add("Salary", typeof(System.String));
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row["Fname"] = "Mathew";
row["Lname"] = "Hayden";
row["Salary"] = "5000$";

table.Rows.Add(row);
ds.Tables.Add(table);

orpt.Load(MapPath("CrystalReport3.rpt"));
orpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = orpt;
```

Records are not displayed in CrystalReport3.rpt when I'm going to run the program.
Please tell me how to set these coloums in Crystal Reports 3!

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you move your code from the Page_Load to the **Page_Init event handler** of the ASP.NET page?

Try to set the [**AutoDataBind** property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226805.aspx) to "true":

> Gets or sets whether automatic data
>   binding to a report source is used. If
>   the value is set to True, the
>   DataBind() method is called after
>   OnInit() or Page_Init() events.

Another tip: did you try to **call the RefreshReport()** (or Refresh() in older versions) method of your CrystalReportViewer1 object?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
orpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
```

Do

```
orpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["table_name"]);
```

table_name is the table name you gave for the table